# x86 Assembly on Linux and Windows

Tags: c, assembly, x86, disassembly

I was wondering if there would be any major difference between disassembling c-code on a Linux and Windows machine. I have an okay understanding of c and 32-bit assembly-intel syntax. (I'll need to do some review). I know the instructions should be the same but the only thing I can thing of that might be different is the system calls. Will anything else be different?

Comment: The calling conventions are slightly different (on x86-64 very different) and the way shared libraries (DLL / SO files) work differs significantly.  The system and library functions too differ and different compilers are used, which means the code may prefer different idioms.  But apart from that, it's pretty much the same.

Comment: @fuz i'll focus my efforts on the shared libraries, although i should have known this since they are different OSes. I hope theres enough good documentation cause the book i read on 32-bit assembly on linux left a lot to be desired. Will optimizing the disassembled 'output' reduce the difference between the compilers?